# unable to validate JS form using for..of loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a form with empty field validation. But when i'm trying to submit the form with some input fields filled, it is executing both conditions given under if and else statement.

JS

```
let inputTags = document.querySelectorAll( 'input' )
           
for ( let input of inputTags )
    {
        if ( input.value === "" && !input.classList.contains( 'hidden' ) )
        {
            
            promptMessages( 'All fields are required.' )
            input.focus()
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log( input.value )  
        }
    }
```

How do I ensure that else condition is executed only when all fields are filled and not when some are.
OR
Is there a better way to validate the form by using just JS?

Comment: This is to check all fields are empty: ```inputTags.every(item => item.value === "");```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are checking each input separately and go to the else clause, if the if clause isn't fulfilled. If you want to only execute the else clause, when all fields are filled, then you could for example use a flag outside the for-loop.

```
const inputTags = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let allFilled = true;
       
for (const input of inputTags){
    if (input.value === "" && !input.classList.contains('hidden')){
        promptMessages('All fields are required.');
        input.focus();
        
        // Set the flag to false, since at least one input isn't filled
        allFilled = false;

        break;
    }
}

// Check if flag is true
if (allFilled) {
    // Execute the code, which was previously in the else clause
    console.log( input.value )
}
```

There are other ways to do it, but this is one example.